# Bose-Einstein distribution computed for negative energies?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, chemical-potential

[image]
For Bose-Einstein distribution we've
$\bar{n}_{i}=\frac{g_{i}}{e^{\left(\varepsilon_{i}-\mu\right) / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}-1}$
,$\mu \leq 0$ ( let's assume $\mu<0$).

Near the origin $\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k T} \approx 0$ or $\varepsilon \approx \mu$ we've some number of particles occupying this energy level. But this energy is negative as
$\varepsilon \approx \mu$ and $\mu<0$ so there shouldn't be any particle with this absurd negative energy but the plot shows otherwise.

(Many plots including this one from Wikipedia show a similar trend )

What's wrong with my analysis?
Can anyone please point out my error?
Thank you

Comment: Does this page contain the answer to your question?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176984/why-epsilon-mu-for-bose-einstein-distribution-but-not-for-fermi-dirac?rq=1

Comment: I think that question is not exactly the same as this question, although they are somewhat similar.

Comment: The point is not if that question is exactly the same as yours. It is if you may find there the answer to your question.

Comment: I did study the answer but I didn't answer my question. There is some difference between these two questions and the answers are different as well. But thank you for pointing out the link.